# How to remove blue circle from jquery mobile icon?

Tags: jquery, css

I am unsing jQuery mobile to create a search bar and a menu icon button. The icon looks normal on one site, but on another page with persumably the same code it has a blue circle around it. Just as it would be a a:visited CSS style. However I could not find anything with inspecting the item.

[image]

```
<a href="#right-panel" data-icon="bars" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" style="position:absolute;right:10px;top:6px;">Menu</a>
```

I tried to add this as indicated on SO:

```
class="ui-nodisc-icon"
```

But this will remove the inner icon leaving the blue circle.

What could be the reason for this and how to remove the circle?

Comment: How can I see more than an image of this?

Comment: I have a staging environment with a htaccess pw which I could msg you.

Comment: I'm not seeing that circle when I test it. It might help to include a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Does not seem to.

Comment: The two blue things I see are [active an focus states](https://jsfiddle.net/gs1r3atz/). Might be one of those.

Comment: The blue circle arround the menu icon on the right is on any search page header and not depending on focus state.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190112/discussion-between-merlin-and-showdev).

Comment: Was this resolved?

Comment: No unfortunatelly not.